# Save images on Google Storage on javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, amazon-s3, google-cloud-storage

My goal is to store an image on S3 or Google Storage and save the link to the database. How can I do it? There is some free solution?

Can someone link me a code sample for to do that?
I never used Google Storage or S3 before.

I pick an image like that:

```
 handleImage = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let reader = new FileReader();
    let file = e.target.files[0];

    reader.onloadend = () => {
        this.setState({
            file: file,
            image: reader.result
        });
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    this.setState({ imgchange: true })
}
```

And then send it to server:

```
        this.props.editUser({
            img: this.state.image,                
        })
```

My server is written with node.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done this exact thing before, though I'm not claiming I had the most straightforward way.

1) sent the image from the client side to the server as a base64 image, took that image, 2) created a buffer, and 3) then used imageMagick to to stream it to my google cloud bucket. Lastly, 4) stored that link to the google cloud bucket on the object in your database as the `imgLink` or what have you so it can show in your front-end application.

**Some important things to require at the top**

```
var gm = require('gm').subClass({ imageMagick: true });
var gcs = require('@google-cloud/storage')({
      keyFilename: sails.config.gcloud.keyFileName,
      projectId: sails.config.gcloud.projectId
});
var bucket = gcs.bucket(sails.config.gcloud.bucketname);
```

**Step 1 - Sending base64 image to backend service and decoding it**

```
imageControllerFirstHitAtEndpoint: function (req, res) {

   PictureService.uploadPictureCDNReturnLink(req.body.picture, function (err, imageLink) {
        if (err) {
            // Handle error...
        }

         // Success, save that imageLink to whatever db object you want
   } 
}
```

**Step 2 and 3 - Create buffer with base64 data and Stream it to Google Cloud Bucket**

```
// Step 2 create buffer with base64 data
uploadPictureCDNReturnLink: function(picDataInBase64, cb) {
    var imageBuffer;

    imageBuffer = PictureService.bufferFromBase64(picDataInBase64);
    var file = bucket.file('cool-file-name');

    // Step 3 stream it to where it needs to go
    gm(imageBuffer)
        .stream()
        .pipe(file.createWriteStream())
        .on('finish', function() {

        file.getMetadata(function(err, metadata) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("Error getting metadata from google cloud", err);
                return cb(err);
            }

            cb(null, metadata.mediaLink);
        });

    }).on('error', function(err) {
        console.log("Got an error uploading to Cloud Storage:", err);
        cb(err);
    });
}
```

**Step 4 - Save that imageLink to wherever you want**

Won't spell this out totally for you, not that hard. Something kinda like:

```
Organization.findOne(req.body.orgID).exec(function (err, organization) {
    if(!organization) {
        return res.json(400, { error: "No organization with id: " + req.param('id') });
    }
    if (err) {
        return res.json(400, err);
    }
    organization.pictureLink = imageLink;
    organization.save(function (err) {
        return res.json(organization);
    });
});
```

Hope that helps! Should give you an idea of one way to do it.

**P.S.** A lot of that stuff might be using Sails-like NodeJS conventions, Sails is my backend framework of choice.

Comment: I don't understand PictureService, I can stream directly the base64?